# Default naming based on number of existing objects Python

Tags: python, class, counter, default

I have made a class to create a node and I would like to create a default name based on the amount of nodes created. I am able to print the amount of nodes existing, however when using an fstring to refer to the counter results in "N0".

Using Node.counter inside the fstring results in a NameError "Node is not defined".

Any ideas how to fix this default naming? e.g. 6th node's name = N6

class Node():
counter = 0

```
def __init__(self,x,y,z, name=f"N{counter}" ):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
    self.name = name

    Node.counter += 1


nodes = []
for i in range(10):
    nodes.append(Node(1,2,3))

print(vars(nodes[5]))

print(Node.counter)
```

Results in:

```
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3, 'name': 'N0'}
10
```

Comment: You can't do it as part of the default argument value. Do it within `__init__`'s body.

Comment: Sometimes it's easier than you think. The following works fine, thanks!
`    def __init__(self,x,y,z, name=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.name = Node.counter if name == None else name
`